# Why is my component unable to access data from my reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am writing a React app in which somebody can sign up as a business or user, and a user is able to search for a business by name. I do not understand why I am getting an error when trying to render my search component, saying "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')". I do not understand why I am getting this error because I believe I am passing in the appropriate data via my reducers and the Redux store. This is my search component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BusinessCard from '../Business/BusinessCard'
import { Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class Businesses extends Component {
    state = {newSearch: ""}


    handleInputChange = e => {
        this.setState({newSearch: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        const { businessesReducer} = this.props;
        
        let businessesMatch = businessesReducer.businesses.filter( (business ) => business.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.newSearch.toLowerCase()))
        return (
            <div>
               <input placeholder="Search Events and Services Near You" value={this.state.newSearch} name="businessName" type="text" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />

               <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3}>
               { businessesMatch.map((business, id) => <BusinessCard key={id} business={business} />)}
               </Card.Group>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return ({
      businessesReducer: state.businessesReducer
     })
  }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Businesses);
```

My businesses reducer:

```
const initialState = 
{
    businesses:[],
    isLoading: false
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOADING':
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case "GET_ALL_BUSINESSES_SUCCESS": 
            return { ...state,
                    businesses: action.businesses,
                    isLoading: false
            }
            
    
    default:
            return state
    }
}
```

BusinessCard.js (which I am trying to render per the user's search)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Card } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 
class BusinessCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
 
  render(){
    const { business, businessesReducer } = this.props;

    return(
      
       <Card>
            <div key={business.id} >

                <Card.Content>
                    <Card.Header><strong>{business.name}</strong></Card.Header>
              
                </Card.Content>
             </div>
        </Card>
   
    )
  }
}


 
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    businesses: state.businesses,
    businessesReducer: state.businessesReducer
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BusinessCard);
```

And App.js

```
import { getAllBusinesses } from './actions/business/business';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';


class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllBusinesses();  
}

render() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
    <div className="App">
    <NavBar />


    <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/services" component={Services} /> 
          <Route path="/shop" component={Shop}/>
          <Route path="/login-signup" component={LoginContainer}/>
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
          <Route path="/business-signup" component={BusinessSignup}/>
          <Route path="/professional-signup" component={ProfessionalSignup}/>
          <Route path="/search" component={Businesses}/>
    </Switch> 

    </div>
</Router>
  )
}

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    businessesReducer: state.businessesReducer
   }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getAllBusinesses})(App);
```

Does anybody have any idea why my search component cannot access "business" and its properties? Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: I had issues with mapStateToProps before. now I am using `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` which are way more easy to understand and control. I suggest you to learn them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: It would be good if you could show `getAllBusinesses`.
2: Please make sure if data exists  in your store, you can use [redux-dev-tools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) for that.
3: The first time that your component renders there is no data in your store and it's just an empty array so please first check if `name` exists and has value then try to convert it to lower case.
It would be something like this:

```
  let businessesMatch = businessesReducer.businesses.filter(
          (business) =>
            business.name &&
            business.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(this.state.newSearch.toLowerCase())
        );
```

Or if with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
let businessesMatch = businessesReducer.businesses.filter((business) =>
  business?.name
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(this.state.newSearch.toLowerCase())
);
```

If none of these help please provide more information like a code sandbox.